# InetAddress.toString generates a lot of garbage in SocketOutputStream.socketWrite

Tags: java, sockets, io, garbage-collection

I am looking at memory allocations of an application that writes to sockets, and I see that a lot of allocations are done in `SocketOutputStream.socketWrite` in `InetAddress`:

[image: Mission Control allocations]

Is there a way do get rid of these allocations?

I am profiling on Windows using Java 1.8.0_40.

Below is the source code of SocketOutputStream from jdk 1.8, I do not see the code that can allocate these objects

```
private native void socketWrite0(FileDescriptor fd, byte[] b, int off,
                                 int len) throws IOException;    

/**
 * Writes to the socket with appropriate locking of the
 * FileDescriptor.
 * @param b the data to be written
 * @param off the start offset in the data
 * @param len the number of bytes that are written
 * @exception IOException If an I/O error has occurred.
 */
private void socketWrite(byte b[], int off, int len) throws IOException {

    if (len <= 0 || off < 0 || off + len > b.length) {
        if (len == 0) {
            return;
        }
        throw new ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException();
    }

    FileDescriptor fd = impl.acquireFD();
    try {
        socketWrite0(fd, b, off, len);
    } catch (SocketException se) {
        if (se instanceof sun.net.ConnectionResetException) {
            impl.setConnectionResetPending();
            se = new SocketException("Connection reset");
        }
        if (impl.isClosedOrPending()) {
            throw new SocketException("Socket closed");
        } else {
            throw se;
        }
    } finally {
        impl.releaseFD();
    }
}
```

Comment: Curious. There's no code in JDK 6 that would do that. Must have been added later.

Comment: @EJP I also do not see  it in jdk 8

Comment: are you using some tool or library that might weave instrumentation code into those methods?

Comment: @the8472 I start it from Idea in "run" mode